# Unable to detect "cross slide" gesture when element is scrollable

Tags: windows-8, touch, winjs, gestures

I'm currently trying to detect a cross-slide gesture on a `div` using the `Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer` class.

I have been able to successfully achieve the detection of this gesture *except* when the element is in a scrollable region.

Specifically, when it *is* in a scrollable region, I receive an `MSPointerCancel` event almost immediately after the `MSPointerDown` event -- if I move the touch interaction slowly, I do see *some* `MSPointerMove` events, but then it goes off and cancels it.

Digging into the `WinJS.UI.ListView` implementation, I'm pretty much doing the same things. That behavior *does* work, so I don't believe this is an issue with drivers or the simulator.

To see this code cross sliding, change the CSS as follows:

`.container`: Change `width: 3000px` to `width: 300px`

**Sample Code**

This code can be tested by creating a Blank JavaScript application in Visual Studio, and pasting the code in where discussed below.

*JavaScript, end of Default.js*

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("Sample", {
    Swiper: WinJS.Class.define(function (el, options) {
        this.element = el;
        WinJS.UI.setOptions(options);
        this.mouseUp = this.mouseUp.bind(this);
        this.keyPress = this.keyPress.bind(this);

        //el.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseUp, true);
        el.addEventListener("keypress", this.keyPress);

        // Gesture events
        this.pointerDown = this.pointerDown.bind(this);
        this.pointerMove = this.pointerMove.bind(this);
        this.pointerUp = this.pointerUp.bind(this);
        this.pointerCancel = this.pointerCancel.bind(this);

        el.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", this.pointerDown, true);
        el.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", this.pointerMove, true);
        el.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", this.pointerUp, true);
        el.addEventListener("MSPointerCancel", this.pointerCancel, true);
    }, {
        element: null,
        _recognizer: null,
        wasSelected: false,
        currentTarget: null,
        pointer: null,
        mouseUp: function (e) {
            if(!e) {
                return;
            }

            if(e.button !== Sample.Swiper.RIGHT_MOUSE) {
                return;
            }

            if (!WinJS.Utilities.hasClass(e.srcElement, "swipeable")) {
                return;
            }

            this._toggleSelection(e.srcElement);
        },
        keyPress: function (e) {
            if (!e) {
                return;
            }

            if (e.keyCode !== WinJS.Utilities.Key.space) {
                return;
            }

            if (!WinJS.Utilities.hasClass(e.srcElement, "swipeable")) {
                return;
            }

            this._toggleSelection(e.srcElement);
        },
        pointerDown: function (e) {
            console.log("Pointer: Down");
            if (!WinJS.Utilities.hasClass(e.srcElement, "swipeable")) {
                return;
            }

            var p = Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint.getCurrentPoint(e.pointerId);
            var touch = (e.pointerType === Sample.Swiper.TOUCH);
            var pointerProperties = p.properties;
            this.pointer = e.pointerId;
            if (!touch) {
                this.mouseUp(e);
                return;
            }

            this.currentTarget = e.srcElement;
            window.proxy.msSetPointerCapture(p.pointerId);
            this._getRecognizer().processDownEvent(p);

            //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        pointerMove: function (e) {
            if (e.pointerId !== this.pointer) {
                return;
            }
            console.log("Pointer: Move");
            var ips = Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint.getIntermediatePoints(e.pointerId);
            this._getRecognizer().processMoveEvents(ips);
            //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        },
        pointerUp: function (e) {
            if (e.pointerId !== this.pointer) {
                return;
            }
            console.log("Pointer: Up");
            var p = Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint.getCurrentPoint(e.pointerId);
            this._getRecognizer().processUpEvent(p);
            //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        },
        pointerCancel: function (e) {
            if (e.pointerId !== this.pointer) {
                return;
            }

            console.log("Pointer: Canceled");
            this._getRecognizer().completeGesture();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        },

        _toggleSelection: function (el) {
            WinJS.Utilities.toggleClass(el, "selected");
        },
        _getRecognizer: function () {
            if (this._recognizer) {
                return this._recognizer;
            }

            var gr = new Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer();
            gr.showGestureFeedback = false;
            var thresholds = gr.crossSlideThresholds;
            thresholds.selectionStart = WinJS.UI._VERTICAL_SWIPE_SELECTION_THRESHOLD;
            thresholds.speedBumpStart = WinJS.UI._VERTICAL_SWIPE_SPEED_BUMP_START;
            thresholds.speedBumpEnd = WinJS.UI._VERTICAL_SWIPE_SPEED_BUMP_END;
            thresholds.rearrangeStart = null;

            gr.crossSlideThresholds = thresholds;
            gr.crossSlideHorizontally = false;
            var settings = Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings;
            gr.gestureSettings = settings.crossSlide;
            gr.addEventListener("crosssliding", function (e) {
                var el = this.currentTarget || document.createElement("div");
                console.log("CrossSlide State: " + e.crossSlidingState);
                switch (e.crossSlidingState) {
                    case Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlidingState.selecting:
                        this.wasSelected = true;
                        break;

                    case Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlidingState.completed:
                        if (this.wasSelected) {
                            this._toggleSelection(this.currentTarget);
                        }
                        this.wasSelected = false;
                        this.currentTarget = false;
                        break;

                    default:
                        this.wasSelected = false;
                        break;
                }
            }.bind(this));
            gr.addEventListener("manipulationstarted", function (e) {
                debugger;
            });
            this._recognizer = gr;

            return gr;
        }
    }, {
        RIGHT_MOUSE: 2,
        TOUCH: 2,
    }),
});
```

*HTML, replace body in default.html*

```
<body>
    <div class="scroller" data-win-control="Sample.Swiper">
        <div id="proxy"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item swipeable"
                tabindex="0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

*CSS, add to default.css*

```
.scroller {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -ms-touch-action: auto;
}
.container {
    width: 3000px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 100px 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 100px 1fr;
}

.item {
    background-color: red;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
}

.selected {
    outline-color: white;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-width: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `-ms-touch-action` requires "fixing" in a specific panning axis for direct manipulation. So, if you want a vertical cross slide (e.g. sliding the finger), then you need to ensure that the element you wish to detect cross sliding on has `-ms-touch-action` set to `pan-x`, to enable panning horizontally, but not vertically. The scroller should have `-ms-touch-action` set to `auto`

(This will teach me to look at the intellisense in VS, rather than looking at the documentation; I knew there was something here)